# Calling methods on a List object of type Class

Tags: java

I have made a List with the type of a child class. Why can't I call on the methods defined in the child class?

```
    int desktopID = 0;
    Random randomID = new Random();
    List<MessageHandler> test = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        desktopID = randomID.nextInt(10);
        System.out.println(desktopID);
        test.storeMessage("Message Number: "+ i, desktopID);
    }

    System.out.println(test.getRecentMessage(desktopID).toString());
```

Comment: Because the compiler has no evidence that at Runtime your `List` will be of the so-called "child-type". :)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking - but you appear to be trying to call methods on a null reference, for one thing. And `List<T>` doesn't contain a `getRecentMessage` method...

Comment: `test` is a `List` which only defines certain methods, and you can't call methods it doesn't define. If you have a sub-class of `List` you have to define `test` as that sub-class.  Ideally you shouldn't sub-class a collection but instead wrap it esp as you don't appear to need any of the methods `List` provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some Background**

It not exactly clear what your asking... but it *sounds* like you want to know why you can't call the methods defined in `MessageHandler` from your list `test` of type `List<MessageHandler>`.

The definition of `List<E>` in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) explains that the parameter E is the type that the list can contain. The `add(E e)` method, for example, will inherit from this and only allow items of type `E` to be added to the list. What this does *not* mean is that you can call the methods defined within class `E` from the `List<E>` object.

For example, I would not be able write this (where `.getRGB()` [is a method from the Color Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB())):

```
 List<Color> colorList = new ArrayList<>;
 colorList.getRGB();
```

However I would be able to write this. Notice how I added a `Color` object to the list and am getting it from the list to call the method on it:

```
 List<Color> colorList = new ArrayList<>;
 colorList.add(Color.Red);

 colorList.get(0).getRGB();
```

---

**To Answer Your Question**

What this means for you, then, is that you should not call your `.storeMessage(...)` and `.getRecentMessage(...)` on your list `test`. Rather you should be creating an object of type `MessageHandler`, calling your store method on that, and then adding it to the list. Once you've done that you can loop over the list again, get each object from the list, and output the message.

Try this:

```
int desktopID = 0;
Random randomID = new Random();

// Note that I'm instantiating the list before using it!
List<MessageHandler> test = new Arraylist<>;

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    desktopID = randomID.nextInt(10);
    System.out.println(desktopID);

    // Create a MessageHandler object and set the message.
    MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler();
    handler.storeMessage("Message Number: "+ i, desktopID);        

    // Add that method to your list
    test.add(handler);
}

// This is a foreach loop. Very useful! Will iterate over each element in order.
for(MessageHandler handler : test){
    System.out.println(handler.getRecentMessage(desktopID).toString());
}
```

(I've assumed that your MessageHandler object has a default constructor.)

Comment: Wow thank you for the insight :), learnt a few things here. But my main problem was that I didn't instantiate my object and I was trying to call methods on it. And then I got many NullPointerExceptions as a result.

Comment: Pleasure! Good luck.